# How can I remove label from bottom navigation bar in flutter so I can center horizontally my add button?

Tags: flutter, navigationbar, flutter-bottomnavigation

can someone help me with this problem. The only solution i have currently found, is to set both showSelectedLabels and showUnselecedLabels to false. However this will remove all the labels, but i only want to remove the label of the add button. If I just use a placeholder "" for label, my add button is off centred horizontally...

[button off centered horizontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pflkk.png)

[the result i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdyz3.png)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: tabs[_selectedIndex],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        elevation: 10,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: kPrimaryMagentaColor),
        selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              padding: kBottomNavIconLabelSpace,
              child: Icon(
                FeatherIcons.map,
                size: 26.5,
              ),
            ),
            label: 'Map',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              padding: kBottomNavIconLabelSpace,
              child: Icon(
                FeatherIcons.compass,
                size: 28,
              ),
            ),
            label: 'Discover',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kPrimaryMagentaColor,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Icon(
                FeatherIcons.plus,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            label: "",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              padding: kBottomNavIconLabelSpace,
              child: Transform(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                transform: Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi),
                child: Icon(
                  FeatherIcons.messageSquare,
                  size: 28,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            label: 'Inbox',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              padding: kBottomNavIconLabelSpace,
              child: Icon(
                FeatherIcons.calendar,
                size: 28,
              ),
            ),
            label: 'My Activity',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is kinda possible by manipulating the `Text`'s `fontSize`.

First, change all the `label`s you have used for each of the `BottomNavigationBarItem` to use `title` parameter. Like this,

Change `label: 'Map'` to `title: Text('Map')`. Similarly change it with all your `BottomNavigationBarItem`. Since this is not possible using `label` parameter.

Now, for your center `BottomNavigationBarItem` use it like this,

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepPurple, shape: BoxShape.circle),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(14),
      child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
  title: Text("", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 0)),
),
```

So, you are changing two things.

1. Increase `padding` of your `Container` to `EdgeInsets.all(14)` to make the button look bigger.
2. Change `fontSize` using `style: TextStyle(fontSize: 0)`, this make the view invisible.

Now, you have something like this, change the color to whatever you want.

[image]

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot! it worked, yeah the title and label thing also confused me a bit, but cheers!

Comment: No, thanks to you. Because of your question, I got to learn how to use a `BottomNavigationBar`. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Title is deprecated. Use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68604614/4249483

Comment: Good solution but text is deprecated for BottomNavigationBarItem. So you can use  "showSelectedLabels: false", "showUnselectedLabels: false"

Comment: @ErayHamurlu it will hide all labels, but if you want to hide center label but visible other then what can you do?

Answer (score 18):

Add this to the BottomNavigationBar properties

```
showSelectedLabels: false,
showUnselectedLabels: false,
```

Comment: Is there no way to keep the outside labels and just remove the center one with the just the icon though?

Comment: Hello @DennisAshford can you please make your question more clear

Comment: For those who tried it with removing the labels in BottomNavigationBarItem widgets - Do not do this. You still need those labels be there and apply these 2 properties.

Answer (score 2):

You need add in BottomNavigationBar():

```
BottomNavigationBar(iconSize: 40,
   showSelectedLabels: false, //selected item
   showUnselectedLabels: false, //unselected item
   ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use 2 params with

```
showSelectedLabels: false, showUnselectedLabels: false,
```

with `label != ""`

You can get [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68457960/needslayout-is-not-true-error-in-flutter-when-changing-between-screens-wi).

Answer (score 0):

```
    showSelectedLabels: false,**--> This solution**
    showUnselectedLabels: false, **--> This solution**
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.library_books_sharp),
          label: '' **--> This solution**
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_tree_outlined),
          label: '' **--> This solution**
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home_filled),
          label: '' **--> This solution**
      )
    ],
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `showSelectedLabels:true` on  BottomNavigationBar the icons doesnot be on center so try to avoid  showSelectedLabels:true
so remove `showSelectedLabels:true`